# Angular Service does not Retrieve Array Objects through RxJS of

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular app (my first real one).  I have the basic views and structure set up with just junk data being created directly in the class.  I'm not trying to set up services which will return observable junk data, then I will change it to connect to the API and return real data.

Anyway, I am getting a strange error that I don't understand on some services.  I have a service that gets company data like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CompanyData} from './Classes/company';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompanyService {

  constructor() {
  }

  GetCompany(): Observable<CompanyData> {
    return of({ID: 'temp id', Name: 'Test Company'});
  }
}
```

Used in the component like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {CompanyData} from '../Classes/company';
import {CompanyService} from '../company.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-company-data',
  templateUrl: './company-data.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./company-data.component.css']
})
export class CompanyDataComponent implements OnInit {

  Company: CompanyData;

  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.GetCompany();
  }

  GetCompany(): void {
    this.companyService.GetCompany().subscribe(company => this.Company = company);
  }
}
```

This works just fine and the company data for the junk company is displayed as expected just like it was when the object was constructed in the component.

Next, I have a user service that looks like this:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {User} from './Classes/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor() {
  }

  GetUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return of([
      {
        ID: 'user id',
        CompanyID: 'Company ID',
        Email: 'some@email.com',
        Permissions: 10,
        Username: 'Some Username'
      }
    ]);
  }
}
```

Implemented in the component like this:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from '../Classes/user';
import {UserService} from '../user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  Users: User[];

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.GetUsers();
  }

  GetUsers(): void {
    this.userService.GetUsers().subscribe(users => this.Users = users);
  }

}
```

This, however, ends up with 'no data' in the view.  When I load that view in the app I get this error in the console:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.userService.GetUsers is not a function
    at UsersComponent.push../src/app/users/users.component.ts.UsersComponent.GetUsers (users.component.ts:21)
    at UsersComponent.push../src/app/users/users.component.ts.UsersComponent.ngOnInit (users.component.ts:17)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:20665)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:21929)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:21891)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:22525)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:22485)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (UsersComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:22477)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21873)
```

The only difference I can see is that one is an array and one is a single object, but I don't see why that would make a difference would it?  I looked at the tutorial app for Angular and their heroes return as an Observable which should be the same...

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, nevermind.  Killed the Angular server and restarted it and it's returning correctly now...  Need to remember to make that the goto first step for debugging Angular it seems.